In Java, avoiding null dereferences when calling super(...) in constructor
I am using Java 21.
I have two classes:
abstract class MySuperClass {
    private final Object mySuperField;
    MySuperClass(Object myField) {
        this.mySuperField = myField;
    }
    public Object getMySuperField() {
        return mySuperField;
    }
}

public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
    private final Object mySubField;
    public MySubClass(MySubClass toCopy) {
        super(toCopy.getMySuperField());
        this.mySubField = toCopy.mySubField;
    }
}

The class MySubClass has a copy constructor, as shown above.
I want to avoid throwing a NullPointerException in the MySubClass constructor if the toCopy argument is null, and would rather throw my own exception. But of course, the call to super(...) must be the first line in the constructor.
Is there some Java pattern which I can use to do my own argument validation before calling super(...)?
I have tried a few different things, but they all seem ugly/hacky, like passing nulls into the super class constructor and not doing validation in the super class, and then doing the argument validation after the call to super(...) in the subclass, or making mySuperField in MySuperClass not final, and providing a setter in the super class. There must be something better.
Of everything I have tried, this might be the best option, but it still feels hacky.
public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
    private final Object mySubField;
    public MySubClass(MySubClass toCopy) {
        super(toCopy == null ? null : toCopy.getMySuperField());
        if (toCopy == null) {
            // Throw my exception
        }
        this.mySubField = toCopy.mySubField;
    }
}


Are you allowed to modify the parent class? Like the addition of an assertion to the constructor or a new constructor for instances of MySuperClass and child classes?

Hi, @pebbleunit, I can modify the parent class.

Are you specifically asking to validate the arguments before the super() call, or is it something else I'm missing? Just want to make sure, because "avoid throwing an [NPE] in the MySubClass could be either (1) not throwing it late, (2) specifcally not throwing an NPE from a dereference or (3) not throwing an NPE at all.

Hi, @username, I want to throw my own exception instead of the NPE. Thank you for check.

Is adding a constructor to MySuperClass an option?  Like protected MySuperClass(MySuperClass toCopy)?

Hi, @VGR, yes, adding a constructor to MySuperClass is possible. Both classes are my classes.

Unfortunately, there is no JDK builtin to do this that doesn't use a NullPointerException (though if an NPE would work with a custom message, you can use Objects.requireNonNull).
However, this could be accomplished with a static method in MySubClass, without any modifications to MySuperClass. This works similarly to Objects.requireNonNull:
public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {

    private static Object notNull(Object obj, Throwable onNull) throws Throwable {
        if (obj == null) throw onNull; // onNull cannot be null
        else return obj;
    }

    private final Object mySubField;
    public MySubClass(MySubClass toCopy) throws Throwable {
        super(
            notNull(
                toCopy,
                new AssertionError("Replace with something that makes sense")
           ).getMySuperField()
        );
        this.mySubField = toCopy.mySubField;
    }
}

This could be improved in a couple ways (e.g. generics for object and exception, avoiding throws Throwable) but this implementation should be the lowest common denominator (and should work on all JDKs).
Edit: For convenience, here's a better implementation with generics and better handling:
private static <T, E extends Exception> T notNull(T obj, E onErr) throws E {
    if (obj == null) throw Objects.requireNonNull(onErr, "Error must not be null");
    else return obj;
}


Thank you, @username. It appears that Slaw improved on your answer, but you answered first and this answer satisfies my need, so I accepted your answer. Thank you!

Add a copy constructor to the superclass
If you control the superclass and can modify it, then I believe the cleanest solution is to add a copy constructor to the superclass.
// could have protected visibility (or even package-private if all
// subclasses are in the same package)
public MySuperClass(MySuperClass toCopy) {
  if (toCopy == null) {
    // throw exception
  }
  // ...
}

Then the subclass's copy constructor would simply look like the following:
public MySubClass(MySubClass toCopy) {
  super(toCopy); // won't return normally if 'toCopy' is null
  // ...
}

Use a static method for the validation
If you can't modify the superclass to perform the validation there, or if you are delegating to another constructor in the same class and must pre-validate the argument, then a relatively common solution is to use a static method to perform the validation.
public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {

  private static MySubClass validate(MySubClass arg) {
    if (arg == null) {
      // throw exception
    }
    return arg;
  }

  public MySubClass(MySubClass toCopy) {
    // 'validate' won't return normally if 'toCopy' is null
    super(validate(toCopy).getMySuperField());
    // ...
  }
}

Note validate here works similarly to Objects::requireNonNull(T). If you find yourself performing many similar validations then you could create your own utility class for this. Or find an existing library that provides such a utility class for you. Also, if you don't mind throwing an NPE but with a custom message, then you can use the Objects::requireNonNull(T,String) or Objects::requireNonNull(T,Supplier) overloads.
Preview Features
If you don't mind using preview features then check out:

Java 22 – JEP 447: Statements before super(...) (Preview)
Java 23 – JEP 482: Flexible Constructor Bodies (Second Preview)
Java 24 – JEP 492: Flexible Constructor Bodies (Third Preview)

This would let you do the following in the subclass's constructor:
public MySubClass(MySubClass toCopy) {
  if (toCopy == null) {
    // throw exception
  }
  super(toCopy.getMySuperField());
  // ...
}


Thank you, Slaw. The information about preview features is very helpful! I will watch these features. Unfortunately, adding a copy constructor for "toCopy" to MySuperClass is not optimal, though admittedly unclear from my example. MySuperClass relies on an object of type "toCopy.mySuperField" to construct it, and adding a dependency on objects of type "toCopy" seems like a different way to inappropriately "bend" the code, but the static validatation is helpful, as @username first suggested.

+1 for the better explanation (than mine), especially the copy constructor. However, I would personally parameterize the validate method to allow reuse for other potential operations. Then again, this may be a unique exception.

@AmateurLinguist Typically, copy constructors are added throughout the class hierarchy. Doing it that way means each class is responsible for copying its own fields and no others. It also means you don't have to modify the code as much if you ever add or remove fields from a class. Note the argument of the copy constructor in MySuperClass has a type of MySuperClass, so you're really only adding a "dependency" on itself. Plus, that's the instance you're calling getMySuperField() on in the first place.
